# Horizontal spanning width not matching up

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am using TikZ nodes within a tikzpicture environment to achieve the placement of all my subfigures.
In the attached figure, it can be seen that in the second row, the total horizontal width exceeds that of the first row.  This is also the case in the third row.

What can be done such that all the vertical borders on the outer right hand side of the figure line up exactly?

Attached also is my current working example.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}}

\newlength{\myheight}
\settoheight{\myheight}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw,rectangle,ultra thick] (mge) {\includegraphics[width=\mywidth]{example-image-a}};

\node[draw,rectangle,ultra thick,right = 0pt of mge.east,anchor=west] (maj) {\includegraphics[height=\myheight]{example-grid-100x100pt}};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\path let \p{1}=(mge.west),\p{2}=(maj.east),\n{x dist}={0.50*abs(\x{2}-\x{1}-\the\pgflinewidth)} in
    node[draw,rectangle,ultra thick,below = 0pt of mge.south west, anchor=north west] (loess) {\includegraphics[width=\n{x dist}]{example-image-b}};

\path let \p{1}=(mge.west),\p{2}=(maj.east),\n{x dist}={0.50*abs(\x{2}-\x{1}-\the\pgflinewidth)},\p3=(loess.south),\p4=(loess.north),\n{y dist}={abs(\y{4}-\y{3}-2*\pgflinewidth)} in
    node[draw,rectangle,ultra thick,right= 0pt of loess.east, anchor=west,minimum height=\n{y dist}] (masses) {\includegraphics[width=\n{x dist}]{example-image-c}};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\path let \p{1}=(mge.west),\p{2}=(maj.east),\n{x dist}={abs(\x{2}-\x{1}-\the\pgflinewidth)} in
    node[draw,rectangle,ultra thick,below = 0pt of loess.south west,anchor=north west] (chi2) {\includegraphics[width={\n{x dist}}]{example-image-golden}};

\node[above=0pt of mge.north west,anchor=south west]{\Huge{ESO349-010}};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: how the output looks like]

Comment: One small thing: `\pgflinewidth` will be the default line width of 0.4pt I think, not the `ultra thick` 1.6pt you've used. The `inner sep` also needs to be taken into account I think. (By the way, if you can use the images from the `mwe` package to illustrate the problem it makes it easier to test, as most people will have that package. See the manual for a complete list, some filenames are `example-image`, `example-image-16x10`, `example-image-a`. If the package is installed, writing for example `\includegraphics{example-image}` will work.)

Comment: Thank you, I have made the changes concerning the example images.

Answer (score 2):

The code below seems to work correctly. Basically you just have to consider the `ultra thick` line width and `inner sep` of the nodes, as I mentioned in my comment. In more detail:

Moving from left to right across the two first images, the elements taking up horizontal space are

```
(lw)(is)(img1)(is)(lw)(lw)(is)(img2)(is)(lw)
```

or

```
4×lw + 4×is + (img1 + img2)
```

where `lw` is the line width of an `ultra thick` line, `is` is the default `inner sep` of nodes and `img` is the width of the images. The anchors are placed on the outer border of the drawn line, so `\x{2}-\x{1}` in your code is the sum of all those elements. *Almost.* The `inner sep` is the distance from the node content to the surrounding path, and the `node` border is drawn in the middle of this path. This means that half the width of the line extends into the region defined by the `inner sep`. The following example shows this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [line width=4pt,inner sep=0pt,draw=blue,draw opacity=0.5] (a) {text};
\fill[red] (a.west) circle[radius=0.5pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What this means is that the the width of your two images become

```
\x{2} - \x{1} = 2×lw + 4×is + (img1 + img2)
```

Hence, the width of the two images in the second row becomes

```
0.5×[\x{2} - \x{1} - (2×lw + 4×is)]
```

The width of an `ultra thick` line is given by the manual as `1.6pt`, and the default `inner sep` as `0.333em`.

---

Minor comment: `\Huge` is not a command that takes an argument, it should be `{\Huge text}`, not `\Huge{text}`. In a node the brace pair is not needed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}}

\newlength{\myheight}
\settoheight{\myheight}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}}


\node [draw,rectangle,ultra thick] (mge) {\includegraphics[width=\mywidth]{example-image-a}};

\node[draw,rectangle,ultra thick,right = 0pt of mge.east,anchor=west] (maj) {\includegraphics[height=\myheight]{example-grid-100x100pt}};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% 1.6pt: width of an ultra thick line
% 0.333em: default inner sep of nodes

\path let
   \p{1}=(mge.west),
   \p{2}=(maj.east),
   \n{x dist}={0.50*(\x{2}-\x{1})-1.6pt - 2*0.333em}
    in
    node[draw,rectangle,ultra thick,below = 0pt of mge.south west, anchor=north west] (loess) {\includegraphics[width=\n{x dist}]{example-image-b}}
    node[draw,rectangle,ultra thick,below=0pt of maj.south east, anchor= north east] (masses) {\includegraphics[width=\n{x dist}]{example-image-c}};

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\path let
  \p{1}=(mge.west),
  \p{2}=(maj.east),
  \n{x dist}={\x{2}-\x{1}-1.6pt-2*0.333em}
  in
    node[draw,rectangle,ultra thick,below = 0pt of loess.south west,anchor=north west] (chi2) {\includegraphics[width={\n{x dist}}]{example-image-golden}};

\node[above=0pt of mge.north west,anchor=south west]{\Huge ESO349-010};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you determine the width of an ultra thick line and the default inner separation?

Comment: @Henri Looked in the manual.